# Apply Custom Styles to the Active Date in Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-datepicker

I am currently using the bootstrap-datepicker with Bootstrap 5. I am attempting to modify the background color of the active date within the date picker. However, it seems that my custom styling is being overridden.

After reading through the docs, I am unable to successfully change the background color of the active date. Below is a simplified version of my attempts:

```js
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
  format: "MM yyyy",
  startView: 2,
  minViewMode: 1,
  maxViewMode: 2,
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
});
```

```css
.datepicker table tr td span.active.active {
  background-color: red !important;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date">
  <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

I've also attempted [s.kuznetsov's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67265491/bootstrap-datepicker-custom-styles), but was unable to modify the colors as suggested.

Comment: Protip: [never link "here"](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/#here-conceals-what-users-are-clicking).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got your selector. A quick look at things with your browser's document inspector shows classes `active` and `focused` on that element, which is a span. You also have to nullify the background gradient image in some cases.

```js
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
  format: "MM yyyy",
  startView: 2,
  minViewMode: 1,
  maxViewMode: 2,
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
});
```

```css
.datepicker .active,
.datepicker .focused {
  background-color: red !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="m-5">
  <div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```